# How to change the color of the text being entered in text field?

Tags: flutter, dart

**How to change the color in this code**

```
Alert Dialog(
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFF161619),
                  title: Text('Enter Your Name',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0)),
                  content: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                        autofocus: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Name',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontFamily: 'abel',
                                fontSize: 20.0),
                            hintText: 'eg. Raakib Zargar'),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          teamName = value;
                        },
                      ))
                    ],
                  ),
```

[Check This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX3yT.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add TextStyle to the TextField and provide `color` property :

```
     Alert Dialog(
                          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF161619),
                          title: Text('Enter Your Name',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0)),
                          content: Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                  child: TextField(
                see here --->   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                                autofocus: true,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
     underline color --->       enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),),  
                                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),),  
                                    labelText: 'Name',
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontFamily: 'abel',
                                        fontSize: 20.0),
                                    hintText: 'eg. Raakib Zargar'),
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  teamName = value;
                                },
                              ))
                            ],
                          ),
```

Comment: check the image attached to the post, I don't want to change the color of the text, but the text being input by the user.

Comment: yes. It will change the color of input-text to red

Comment: If your query is resolved, I request you mark the answer as accepted.